# rspec's .should fails (outside describe/it block) in Ruby 2?

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-2.0

In Ruby 2, with gem rspec 2.14.1 (Ubuntu's most recent), with Rails not installed, why does this fail?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec'
3 .should == 3

NoMethodError: undefined method `should' for 3:Fixnum
```

I've relied for years on the convenient idiom `x .should == y`.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/syntax-configuration and
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/syntax-configuration say that this syntax is still supported by default.

**Edit:** added "outside describe/it block" to title, as that seems to be the root cause.

Comment: I doubt you can use it outside the `describe`/`it` block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use it outside  a `describe/it` block, it seems you'd have to enable it first, although the documentation states it is enabled by default. I assume that by `enable by default` means within an spec file [[source](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/syntax-configuration)] only. For instance:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :should
  end
end

p 3.should == 3 # true
```

Comment: This is correct. complementing, also prefer `expect` instead of `should` as recommended by [betterspec](http://betterspecs.org/#expect)

Answer (score 3):

rspec-expectations is the gem that adds `should` to every object.  Requiring `rspec` loads only the rspec meta gem (which exists purely to be a single `gem install` that provides all of rspec), but does not automatically load rspec-expectations.  rspec-core allows you to configure it to use something besides rspec-expectations if you wish (such as the stdlib assertions provided by minitest, or wrong), but it loads rspec-expectations by default. To achieve this, if you do not explicitly configure it, it waits to load rspec-expectations until the first `describe` call, for historical reasons, as [explained in my blog post](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2011/11/recent-rspec-configuration-warnings-and-errors).

So, if you want to make `Object#should` immediately available, you simply need to require `rspec/expectations`.  Note that we plan to change the default in RSpec 4 so that `should` is not automatically available without extra config.  Also, as @JonRowe mentioned, this usage isn't really the intended usage.  You can call `foo.should` from any context, but the matcher methods that are meant to work with `should` are not available in all contexts.  You'll need to include `RSpec::Matchers` into your context to make them available.  Consider also switching to the `expect` syntax: it's a newer, non-monkeypatching syntax we've been [recommending for a while now](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax).

Comment: I've been using `.should` like C's `assert()`.  (And just yesterday I poked fun at someone else on SO for using a C idiom instead of a Ruby idiom!)  I'll learn `expect`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported outside of an RSpec example, e.g. inside an `it` block inside a `describe` block. Please don't use it in this fashion.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jon. +1 just so I could increase your rep by an order of magnitude. ;-)