# Use RSpec's "expect" etc. outside a describe ... it block

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm building a web-app automation framework that is designed to allow for:

- automating tasks, of course
- building test scenarios easily

I'm using Capybara to communicate with a browser and I have a library of components with a number of helper functions (login_to_the_back_office, create_customer, etc.).

Now I would like my components to be usable standalone as well as within RSpec tests. This means that my components, as included in the library, are not wrapped around `describe... it...` blocks by default, but they will be at some point when a test uses them and so they should use `expect` and friends as often as possible.

I followed [rspec's .should fails (outside describe/it block) in Ruby 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839718/rspecs-should-fails-outside-describe-it-block-in-ruby-2) to enable `should` and it works (actually just requiring `rspec-expectations` was enough in my case), but I can't figure out how to make expect work.

I think `expect` is defined here https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/expectations/syntax.rb but my knowledge of Ruby's meta-magic is too limited to figure out how to make expect available to my class.

I've tried including `RSpec::Expectations::Syntax` in my class but I still get `undefined method 'expect'` whenever I try to use it.

How can I use `expect` outside of `describe... it...` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

include `::RSpec::Matchers`

```
class A
  include ::RSpec::Matchers
  def test
    expect('1'.to_i).to eq 1
  end

  def failed_test
    expect('1'.to_i).to eq 2
  end
end
A.new.test
# => true
A.new.failed_test
# RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: 
# expected: 2
#      got: 1
```

Comment: yay!! Must be the only module I hadn't tried including :) Thanks!

Comment: @UriAgassi +1 I should start taking RSpec lessons from you. :D BTW Congratulations on http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/topusers

Comment: @uri-agassi How do you make `expect` echo out the assertions as the code runs?  Thans