# Can I use Rspec Expect in a module defined function?

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

I'm trying to move my Cucumber Matcher into a function of a module

```
Then (/^posted "(.*?)" http response should be returned$/) do |arg1|
  expect($post_result.lines.last.to_i).to eq(arg1.to_i)
end
```

The module function as below

```
module AccessFunc
    #  :
    #  : Some require... global variable setting etc
    #  :
  def self.posted_http_response_check(arg1)
    expect($post_result.lines.last.to_i).to eq(arg1.to_i)
  end
end
```

Running my cucumber test with the cucumber matcher could use the Expect. But I can't use the Expect within my module. I tried using

```
include ::RSpec::Matchers
```

as per [Use RSpec's "expect" etc. outside a describe ... it block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624655/use-rspecs-expect-etc-outside-a-describe-it-block) but not successful.

The error I got is

```
undefined method `expect' for AccessFunc:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Could someone shed some light how could I workaround this (e.g. using Expect within a Module.

p/s: I could solve the problem by remove the Module, and define the function *posted_http_response_check* globally.

Comment: is this a piece of test ? if not why do you need an expect in a module .

Comment: Yes, this is one part of test. I'm moving this expect into a module, it's because I plan to use it is various different test scenarios, and hence don't want to have it repeated over the Cucumber Matcher.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to mixin the AccessFunc module, for the scenario steps to recognize this.
Try adding World AccessFunc to your env.rb and see how it goes. Can't say for sure if this will work, definitely worth a try though.